Saving JsonElement with EF Core 8 using Cosmos db returns undefined
I'm using EF Core 8 with CosmosDb and I'm saving a Dictionary<string, JsonElement> and I think the data is saved.
{
    "id": "7015e3d9-d300-4bb6-f441-08dc57de0ee3",
    "Data": {
        "Identifier": {
            "ValueKind": 3
        }
    },
    "Description": "TestApplicationName_7ef73a36-1187-4c41-b999-5d8fa7d0cc89",
...
}

When I call GetData after the SaveData, the value is there (maybe from cache), if it's on other call, like API HttpPost / HttpGet, the values are

ValueKind = Undefined : ""

All the other values are correct including the Dictionary Key, only the JsonElement is undefined.
What am I doing wrong?
public class Data
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public Dictionary<string, JsonElement> Data { get; set; } = [];
}

The save method:
    public async Task<Guid?> AddData(Data data, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var addDataResult = _context.Data.Add(data);

        try
        {
            int result = await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

            if (result > 0)
            {
                return addDataResult.Entity.DataId;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError("(Exception) Adding Data: {application.ApplicationId}, message: {ex.Message}", data.DataId, ex.Message);
        }

        return null;
    }

Load method:
    public async Task<Data?> GetData(Guid dataId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Data? data= await _context.Data.FindAsync([dataId], cancellationToken);

        if (data is not null)
        {
            return data;
        }

        return null;
    }

Thanks in advance.
I


Saving JsonElement with EF Core 8 using Cosmos db returns undefined

The reason for showing undefined is might due to providing vale of id in the data which is going to be saved in the Azure Cosmos DB Container and in Data class it is defined as GUID. While it is GUID the value will be generated unique identifier by itself while storing the data into the container. Try with the below code which saved the data in Azure Cosmos DB Container successfully and also retrieves the saved data as shown in the below output.
public class Data
    {
        public Guid id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public Dictionary<string, string> DataValues { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        public void AddJsonElement(string key, JsonElement value)
        {
            DataValues[key] = value.ToString();
        }

        public JsonElement GetJsonElement(string key)
        {
            if (DataValues.TryGetValue(key, out string value))
            {
                return JsonDocument.Parse(value).RootElement;
            }
            else
            {
                return default(JsonElement);
            }
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Data> Data { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Data>()
                .ToContainer("newCont2") 
                .HasPartitionKey(d => d.id); 
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseCosmos("<connectionString>", "newDb");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
            {
                builder.AddConsole();
            });
            var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();

            try
            {
                using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
                {
                    var testData = new Data
                    {
                        id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        Description = "Test description",
                        DataValues = new Dictionary<string, string>
                        {
                            { "Key1", "{\"Value\": 42}" }, 
                            { "Key2", "{\"Name\": \"John\"}" } 
                        }
                    };

                    await context.Data.AddAsync(testData);
                    await context.SaveChangesAsync();

                    var retrievedData = await context.Data.FirstOrDefaultAsync();

                    if (retrievedData != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Retrieved data:");
                        Console.WriteLine($"Id: {retrievedData.id}");
                        Console.WriteLine($"Description: {retrievedData.Description}");

                        foreach (var kvp in retrievedData.DataValues)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Key: {kvp.Key}, Value: {kvp.Value}");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("No data found.");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.LogError($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

Output:
Retrieved data:
Id: 29e87f3a-9dd1-4f55-9ec0-507bd2d1bb51
Description: Test description
Key: Key1, Value: {"Value": 42}
Key: Key2, Value: {"Name": "John"}
Press any key to exit...

Saved data In Azure Cosmos DB Container:


Yes, I changed JsonElement to String and it started working. It would be good if there EF provides a no workaround solution.
